# .htaccess URL amigável problema PHP

Tags: html, htaccess

Tenho um link assim:

```
<a href="index/pagina=$i"> $i </a>
```

queria que o URL ficasse assim:

```
index/2
```

e estou usando o `.htaccess` assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index?$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Onde esta o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que o problema está no `href` do seu `a`. O `.htaccess` está correto mas o link que você está imprimindo não está.

Deveria ser assim (pra gerar index/$i)

```php
<a href="index/$i"> $i </a>
```

Comment: Ele redireciona mas o css volta todo quebrado

Comment: @BrendolLourençon Adicione `<base href="http://[SEU SITE]/" />` no `head` da sua página e veja se resolve seu problema.

Comment: no caso <base href="http://localhost/" /> ?

Comment: Cara nem sei como te agradecer, deu certo aqui Andre ribeiro muito obrigado !

Comment: sobre o "css quebrado", apenas adicione duas exceções no htaccess. Esse impede aplicar as regras para arquivos existentes fisicamente RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   Esse outro para diretórios: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   Daí nem precisa usar a tag <base>

Comment: vou postar separado porque nao tem quebra de linha nos comentarios

Comment: com o <base href="http://[SEU SITE]/" /> deu certo, eu nao sabia dessa tag, pegou direitinho, obrigado ai galera !

Comment: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

Comment: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d